# Get those li that have sub children ul

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to get those `li` that have children `ul`. I want to set CSS to those `li`. I can't set class because `li` are dynamically print. When I set CSS as below so it set all parent `li` to plus.

```css
.ul{
 width:200px;
 position:relative;
}
.ul li{
   position:relative;
 }
.ul > li:before{
 content : '+';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
<li>List 3
    <ul>
       <li>Sub List 1</li>
       <li>Sub List 2</li>
       <li>Sub List 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>List item 4</li>
</ul>
This is style for that.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close actually. The trick is to style simply each `ul` that is inside a `.ul`. Then move the `+` to where you want it to appear (i.e. after the first line of the parent li).

```css
.ul {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.ul li {
  position: relative;
}
.ul ul::before {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3
    <ul>
      <li>Sub List 1</li>
      <li>Sub List 2</li>
      <li>Sub List 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
</ul>
This is style for that.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because in CSS, you don't have a *parent selector*.

For instance you can't do something like:

```
ul < li { color: #ddd; }
```

or even something like:

```
ul:has(li) { color: #ddd; }
```

This is because there are a lot of performance issues like re-rendering the page if you have such a `parent selector`. That's why W3C guys have not added the parent selector tool.

Look here for reading more into it:

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

[Parent selectors in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)